# How do I make file input optional with ng-file-upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am trying to submit a form with ng-file-upload that contains additional form data. I had it working fine when the file was required, but now the client wants the file upload to be optional. I modified the PHP service to accept the new data, and it works fine.

The issue is displaying a success message when there is no file attached to the form. The data is received and processed fine by the service, but now I can't get it to indicate that the submission was successful.

I really don't want to have to shift gears at this point, and I like ng-file-upload's preview feature. I tried changing the checked variable in the ng-show directive for the success message and setting it in the `.then` function, but that doesn't work.

The only thing I can think of is to branch the code based on whether the file input is present and send it via regular `$http` if it isn't, but is there a better way?

Here's my controller code:

```
app.controller('adController', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
  //$scope.text = "Is this working?";
  $scope.ad = {};
  $scope.isSaving = false; // disables fieldset to prevent accidental double-click submissions
  $scope.successful_post = false;
  $scope.errorClass = function(el) {
    var s = $scope.adApplicationForm[el];
    return (s.$invalid && s.$dirty) ? "has-error" : "";
  };
  $scope.submitForm = function(valid) {
    console.log("Form Submitted" + valid)
    return valid;
  };

  $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    $scope.isSaving = true;

    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'php/upload_ad.php',
      data: {ad: $scope.ad, file: file},
    });

    file.upload.then(function (response) { // success
      $timeout(function () {
        file.result = response.data;
      });
      $scope.isSaving = false;
      $scope.successful_post = true;
    }, function (response) {
      if (response.status > 0)
        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
      // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
  };
}]);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you tried having `ng-required` set to `false` on the directive?

Comment: Yes, it is no longer a required field, and that will allow the form to be submitted. But it still won't give me a success even when the service returns a 200. As far as I can tell, `.then` isn't even being run if it doesn't submit a file.